# ImageView не отображается в FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview

Не могу программно поместить изображение (на основе выбранной позиции в spnner) во FrameLayout

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final FrameLayout forImg=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.forImg);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);
    Spinner spinnerBase = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.baseSpinner);
    spinnerBase.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (position == 1){
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                        (SelectionActivity.this, R.array.k, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                Spinner spinnerSecond=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);
                spinnerSecond.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinnerSecond.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long l) {
                        parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        if (position == 1){
                            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                                    (SelectionActivity.this, R.array.k, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            Spinner spinnerThird=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.thirdSpinner);
                            spinnerThird.setAdapter(adapter);
                            spinnerThird.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
                                    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                    if (position==1){
                                        ImageView img = new ImageView(SelectionActivity.this);
                                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.i);
                                        forImg.addView(img);
                                    }
```

В результате запуска появляется пустое Activity на пару секунд и выбрасывает в MainActivity. Помогите картинку запихать во фрейм.

Comment: для начала `setContentView` повыше поднимите

Comment: @Serodv действительно помогло, а я голову ломаю, что я не так сделал. Оформите как ответ- плюс к карме)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь определить `id` контейнера до размещения пользовательского интерфейса. Достаточно эти две операции поменять местами.